# Batch Converting Numeric to Factor

Tags: r

I am trying to bulk convert `numeric` and `character` class variables to `factor` in R. I feel that this should be simple, but I am running into an issue actually getting it to factor

What I have done is here:

```
>sapply(df, class)
    a           b          c
"numeric"   "numeric"  "numeric" 

>col.names <- c("a", "b", "c")
>df[,col.names] <- sapply(df[,col.names], as.factor)
```

and what I get back it this:

```
>sapply(df, class)
     a            b            c
"character"  "character"  "character"
```

And I am trying to figure out why it wouldn't convert from numeric to factor, and instead is going to character.

Typically the problem is going from factor to numeric, so I haven't been able to find anything about this type of issue.

Comment: Try exactly the same but with `lapply`.

Comment: This worked! Would you be able to tell me why lapply worked and sapply didnt? is it because sapply is simplified over a vector?

Comment: Ivan's answer explains the difference.

Comment: Yes, it is. And the coercion is to the least common denominator, `character`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose, in this case, `sapply()` returns you a matrix, which can not be a factor. Use

```
df[,col.names] <- lapply(df[,col.names], as.factor)
```

as `lapply()` returns list of factors to insert them into your df.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `lapply`. In the following example, I create two equal df's with 4 columns.

```
df <- df2 <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 6:10, c = 11:15, d = 16:20)
col.names <- c("a", "b", "c")

df[,col.names] <- lapply(df[,col.names], as.factor)
sapply(df, class)
#a         b         c         d 
#"factor"  "factor"  "factor" "integer"
```

Note that if you want to change the entire data.frame, you need to write the square brackets, `df2[]`.

```
df2[] <- lapply(df2, as.factor)
sapply(df2, class)
#a        b        c        d 
#"factor" "factor" "factor" "factor"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
df <- data.frame(sapply(df, as.factor))
```

The difference is enclosing it in a data.frame at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `tidyverse` solution.

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- tibble(x = c("blue", "green", y = c(1:2))

data <- data %>%
  mutate(x = factor(x),
         y = factor(y))
```